# Comparing DateTIme Column value with DateTime String SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to compare DateTime string to a DateTime Value Column in DB but its returning me 0 records Here is the query

```
DECLARE @p_date DATETIME
SET @p_date= CONVERT( DATETIME, '9/1/2015 10:06:22 PM', 131 )
SELECT UpdateUserId, UpdateTimeA 
From SubmitSheets 
WHERE CONVERT( DATETIME, UpdateTimeA, 131 ) = @p_date
```

the value in UpdateTimeA column is `2015-09-01 22:06:22.447`

Comment: Do you store in SubmitSheets UpditeTimeA in NVARCHAR column?

Comment: no its type is datetime

Comment: If it's returning 0 records surely it's a data issue?

Comment: @HackoriDotCom: you can see the record in question its same value but in a different format.

Comment: Is it the same value? The value in the table has a second-fraction (after the dot), the value in your variable does not.

Comment: Additionally, are you sure 131 is correct? If I execute `SELECT  CONVERT( DATETIME, '9/1/2015 10:06:22 PM', 131 )` sql server returns `2576-08-04 22:06:22.000`

Comment: yes, this is the problem I need to compare datetime without that fraction,

Answer (score 0):

I think the @p_date parameter is not in same format. Try this:

```
DECLARE @p_date DATETIME
SET @p_date= CONVERT( DATETIME, '9/1/2015 10:06:22 PM')
SELECT UpdateUserId, UpdateTimeA 
From SubmitSheets 
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, (CONVERT(VARCHAR, UpdateTimeA, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, UpdateTimeA, 108)), 131) = CONVERT(DATETIME, @p_date, 131)
```

So another tryout may be

An example:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE
(
    ID  int,
    datet datetime
)

INSERT INTO @a
        (ID, datet)
VALUES  (1 ,  CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 131))
        ,(2 ,  CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 131))
        ,(3 ,  CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 131))
        ,(4 ,  CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 131))
        ,(5 ,  CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 131))
        ,(6 ,  CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 131))
        ,(7 ,  CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 131))
        ,(8 ,  CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 131))
        ,(9 ,  CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 131))



SELECT ID, datet, ConvDatetime
FROM 
    (
        SELECT ID, datet
            ,CONVERT(DATETIME, (CONVERT(VARCHAR, datet, 101) 
            + ' ' 
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR, datet, 108)), 131) AS ConvDatetime
        FROM 
            @a
    ) AS dt
WHERE 
    dt.ConvDatetime= CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                            (CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101) 
                            + ' ' 
                            + CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 108))
                        , 131) -- CONVERT( DATETIME, '9/1/2015 10:06:22 PM', 131 )
```

Comment: It is due to "10:06:22 PM" when it is converted to datetime, 131 format then it produces "2576-08-04 22:06:22.000" where in table data the datetime also have millisecond part ie. like "2015-09-02 17:11:37.380". Either truncate milisecond part or also add milisecond part in where clause. Also year is another on converting ie. 2576-08-04.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, I'm not sure 131 is the right style to convert to datetime (at least, I get a very different value).

If you want to compare dates without the second fraction, you'll have to compare as strings. Converting both dates to a varchar(19) will cut off the fractions.

Comment: @AdilWaqar problem with not 131 see here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp problem with ms which is `000` and `447`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way

```
SELECT UpdateUserId,UpdateTimeA 
From SubmitSheets 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),UpdateTimeA,100) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),CONVERT( DATETIME, '9/1/2015 10:06:22 PM',101),100)
```

Comment: `select CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),'2015-09-01 22:06:22.447',100)` and 
`select CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),CONVERT( DATETIME, '9/1/2015 10:06:22 PM',101),100)` this two statement are returning 2 different values is it working with where clause